# Translate string in Perl

Tags: perl, translate

In PHP, [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) can accept an input of array and replace all occurrence of key within the string, and the **longest keys** will be tried first.

Is there equivalant function in Perl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, simple regex:

```
# Where %h contains your key => value mappings
my $keys = join '|', sort {length($b) <=> length($a)} keys %h;
$a =~ s/($keys)/$h{$1}/g;
```

Comment: You're going to have to sort those keys longest first.

Comment: If you don't sort keys according to their length, this does not use longest keys first.

Comment: Ah, I can see tchrist was faster. But the edit is still wrong, use rather `sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %h` - numeric comparison of length and descending order.

Comment: Also, you should add a `map { quotemeta }` in front of `sort` in case the keys contain regex metacharacters.

Comment: Any limit on the length of regex? In case my array is very large?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than manually building up a regex to evaluate, use [Data::Munge](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Munge)'s list2re function like this:

```
my $re = list2re sort {length($b) <=> length($a)} keys %h;
$a =~ s/($re)/$h{$1}/g;
```